# How to download and execute a file every month invisibly to the user?

Tags: c++, windows

I need a way to download ( from a server ) and execute a file every month automatically and invisibly to the user.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just check the time periodically and do once a month keeping track of the last month you've done?

Comment: Invisibly to the user? What possible reason is there for downloading content without a user's explicit consent? Especially an executable file. No thanks.

Comment: Sorry, that's actionable and I might be held liable too for helping you

Comment: @Ninefingers: cracking I suppose..

Comment: invisibly because it's an update.

Comment: this doesn't sound like a complete question.  What user?  Is she already running some software you gave her?

Comment: @xRobot: <quote>invisibly because it's an update</quote> You still need to ask the user. If you do an update without asking then you will run into a lot of legal problems (Disclaimer. I am not a lawyer ask for real legal advice). Also any program that I find dowloading and executing code on my machine without asking first gets disabled and put in the trash (unless it is security that it running it).

Comment: @xRobot: Don't check for updates on a schedule.  Instead, check when the user starts your application (every time, or every 10th time, or every 30th day, but only when the app gets used).  Users hate it when an application they aren't running is taking up resources.  Installing a "Scheduled task" is still the way to go, but set it to run manually instead of on a periodic schedule, then your app can trigger it.  An app can trigger a task that executes with higher permissions than the app itself (creating the task in the first place requires full admin rights).

Comment: @Ben: "Instead, check when the user starts your application", and *then* on a schedule while the app's running. People sometimes leave apps running for days/weeks/months.

Comment: @Ben Maybe you should post this comment as a real answer. I'd just use the scheduler to do that instead of manually activating the scheduled task. That's exactly what the scheduler is for and the user can disable the action if he does not wish to update every month, or even change the update interval.

Comment: @RedX: I have now done so.  I still think that it's harmful to run update tasks even when the app is completely dormant (hasn't been used in months).  And one advantage of doing it at application startup is that you notice if the task is missing (user copying the application directory to a different computer is a common cause of that) and offer to re-enable update checking.

Comment: Downloading a file and running it invisibly in the background does not imply lack of user consent.

Comment: @Ben Ok i now understand what you meant by when the app get used. You schould not forget that exploits can still be used event if the user does not start the program himself. The exploit might start the application itself if it is needed. I only thought of really installed applications. If it is a portable app the user must undo any action it has done when using the app (creating shortcuts and stuff like that). The checking part is IMHO totally independent of starting an update.

Answer (score 3):

Don't blindly check for updates on a schedule. Instead, check when the user starts your application (every time, or every 10th time, or every 30th day, but only when the app gets used).

Users hate it when an application they aren't running is taking up resources.

As Steve Jessop points out, it may also be good to occasionally check again if the app stays running for a long time.

[Installing a "Scheduled Task"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381841.aspx) is still the way to go, but set it to run manually instead of on a periodic schedule, then your app can trigger it. An app can [trigger a task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380767.aspx) that executes with higher permissions than the app itself (creating the task in the first place requires full admin rights).  The task also [remembers the last time it ran](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380761.aspx) which is useful for keeping traffic down.

Comment: Yes, this is a much better option given the very limited frequency of work.

Comment: @selbie: Which is one of the reasons I don't have iTunes on my computers.  Programs aren't supposed to be running code, even update checks, unless they're, well, *running*.  (I nuke `jusched.exe` as well, I can be informed of new versions by a program that handles a hundred or so apps at once, I don't need or want some background task consuming resources when I'm not using its program.)

Answer (score 1):

An application that you build as a [Windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) will run in the background and can do what you want.

> Microsoft Windows services, formerly
>   known as NT services, enable you to
>   create long-running executable
>   applications that run in their own
>   Windows sessions. These services can
>   be automatically started when the
>   computer boots, can be paused and
>   restarted, and do not show any user
>   interface. These features make
>   services ideal for use on a server or
>   whenever you need long-running
>   functionality that does not interfere
>   with other users who are working on
>   the same computer.

Comment: There's already a service, the Scheduler.  Installing another service just to download an update once a month is a waste.

Answer (score 0):

Least intrusive way is just to check when the application starts.  (Every time, or every 10th time, or whatever).  I know other large apps don't do that, but as a user I really hate it, perceive these apps as "bloat" and avoid when possible.  (Example:  iTunes).  Anything else just clogs up my computer when I'm trying to do something else.

Also, you'd better make sure the code is safe to run; use a digital signature to be sure that the code is really from you.  Otherwise you're vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack:  I could set up an imitation server and send evil code to your users.  (Or hack your server and upload evil code to your server for your users to get.  Etc. etc.)